# Joomla 2 Step Regstration

Tags: joomla, registration

Need to figure out a way to register users in a 2 step process:-

Step 1> Get Username, Email, Password

Step 2> Get other details like address, zip code etc- etc-

1) Are there free extensions for the 2.5 version with which i can do this ?
2) Any articles on hacking the core to fulfill my requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to look for Joomla! extensions free and otherwise is the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/), in your case I would suggest looking in

1. the [Authentication section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication).
2. the [community/social extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities) many of which let you specify additional custom fields for user registrations.

In the commercial space you could look at products like [RSForm!Pro](http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html) that have a plugin to "Create custom user registration forms" and only costs 19€ to get started with. After all you could spend much more than 19€ of your time "hacking the core".